# Just not vs not just

Tags: adverb-placement

Which sentence is correct?

- He might just not be expressing it.
- He might not just be expressing it.

I want to say to a person that another person looks normal but might not be normal because he is not expressing his problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, adverbial ***just*** *(**merely, only, no more than**)* normally modifies the text element immediately following. Thus...

> 1: *He just might not speak*
> ("weakens" ***might***, to imply *It's just possible (but unlikely) that he won't speak*)
> 2: *He might just not speak*
> (weakens the entire negated action ***not speak***, to imply that he may simply remain silent)
> 3: *He might not just speak*
> (weakens ***speak***, to imply that he might do *other* things besides speaking)

---

Thus, in OP's context...

> 4: *He might just not be expressing it*
> (perhaps he's simply failing to express it)
> 5: *He might not just be expressing it*
> (perhaps he's doing something else, ***as well as*** expressing it)

Answer (score 1):

"Just not" means that he is not expressing it. In this context, "just" means something like "simply". Hence: "It could simply be that he is not expressing it."

Fully:

"The answer to our question about this could be as simple as being that he is not expressing it."

On the other hand, "not just" means "not only". It means that he *is* expressing it, but he is *more* than expressing it, he is doing *something else as well* to it.

"It might be the case that not only is he not expressing it, but also ..." (who knows?)

Hence, in this context, your first option seems to be the one you want.